# Djangocms install failing and giving a returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python-3.x, django-cms

I've read the docs and I can't seem to get djangocms to install successfully

I'm using a virtual environment and tried it without it also, and then the normal installation procedure.

Windows 10 OS and I can start a Django project fine

I get the messages:
Creating the project
Please wait while I install dependencies
Dependencies installed
Creating the project
The installation has failed.

---

Check documentation at https://djangocms-installer.readthedocs.io

---

Here is the Traceback

```
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\Lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", mod_spec)

  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)

  File "D:\Development\PYTHON\django_cms\env\Scripts\djangocms.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>

  File "d:\development\python\django_cms\env\lib\site-packages\djangocms_installer\main.py", line 37, in execute
    django.create_project(config_data)

  File "d:\development\python\django_cms\env\lib\site-packages\djangocms_installer\django\__init__.py", line 61, in create_project
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd_args, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\Lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output **kwargs).stdout

  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\Lib\subprocess.py", line 418, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)

**subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['d:\\development\\python\\django_cms\\env\\scripts\\python.exe', 'd:\\development\\python\\django_cms\\env\\scripts\\django-admin.py', 'startproject', 'project_two', 'D:\\Development\\PYTHON\\django_cms\\project_two']' returned non-zero exit status 1.**
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced upon such a problem. It was solved by going up to the PROJECT level.
I.e. you have: c:\myfolder\myenv\Scripts and usually you activate venv here.
So if you want to start a djangocms app, you should change directory to 'myfolder' and run 'djangocms newproject1'. Try the name you never use before now. Or recreate venv to flush previous failed attempts.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem exactly the same as you and solved it by this way:

1. uninstall older `djangocms-installer` by this command: `pip uninstall djangocms-installer`
2. use pip instead of pip3
3. upgrade your pip by this command: `pip install --upgrade pip`
4. install `djangocms-installer` by this command: `pip install djangocms-installer`
5. create you project using this command: `djangocms -f -p [path of project] [project name]` for example `djangocms -f -p ./polls polls`